# Visual Studio and Project don't see new classes/folders etc after adding new classes and folders for the project cloned from GIT

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, github

I cloned my project from the github repository.Now i made a new folder in this project and added here a class with a namespace.However, when i tried to add a using command with this namespace(c#) to another class(this class was in my project from the start, because it was in git repo), I noticed that project doesn't see this Folder/Class/Namespace.I don't really know what can I do so I'll be very grateful if you will help me(VS 2019)

Comment: Is it a .NET Core project or .NET Framework one?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the project file (unload the project and edit proj file)

Check if the Folder is in there.
If not,  you can manually insert it and reload the project.

Oh and in case that you reference to another project, check if the newer projects framework version is not over the referencing project.
This could also be a possible error.

Comment: i don't reference to anothet proj, that' my git. And can you please tell me, how can i check that my folder is in project?

Comment: Right click the project - unload
right click again and edit .csproj

Then you can find something like this:
''' 
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="App_Start\AutoMapperConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\BundleConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\ContainerJobActivator.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\FilterConfig.cs" />

...
'''
Check if you find your files there

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite old topic, but I've got the same issue today. And the reason was that I created repo with a name containing space, like "My repo".
In the link generated by git, repo name was "My%20repo". And the same directory was created on my local machine (os: win 10).
It appears that VS can't treat "My%20repo" as valid directory name, and no directory nor file has been added to project on creation. Strange thing is, any file or directory created later has been perfectly visible.
So I've just changed directory name to get rid of this "%20" part, now it works just as supposed.
Not sure if that's true reason. But that's my experience I wanted to share :)

Answer (score -1):

Follow this link, may be it could help:

[visual-studio-2019-doesnt-include-on-csproj-new-files](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2019-doesnt-include-on-csproj-new-fi/610723)

This solve the issue: update the package Microsoft.Net.Compiler to the latest version, compile and try adding a new class to your project again.

Comment: @Yunnosch updated.